# Loading user information from last login in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am developing an app in android. For this, I am getting users to login using their Facebook or Google IDs. I have stored information on the user logins in my database.

Now, when the app is opened the next time around, I want to fetch the details of the last logged in account and load user details based on that.

One way in which I thought I can do this is by handling it as a SharedPreference.

Another way in which I thought I can do this is to keep a column in my user details table to mark this as the last logged in account.

I wanted to know if either of these is the preferred method to implement this. Or is there some other different way to implement this?

Comment: For me, SharedPreferences

Comment: Use SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing a token returned from the server in the shared prefs is a fine way to do this. Just don't store the actual account information in shared prefs.

Answer (score 1):

I find [Remember](https://github.com/tumblr/Remember) really handy in this case and it's based on SharedPreference.

Typical implementation:

```
private void signIn() {
    String username = mUsernameEditText.getText().toString();
    ...

    if (username.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
        // show error dialog
    } else {
        Remember.putString(Constant.LAST_USED_USERNAME, username);
        YourApi.getInstance().login(username, password);
    }
}
```

Then on your `onCreateView()` or wherever you intialize your UI of your login screen

```
...
String lastLogin = Remember.getString(Constant.LAST_USED_USERNAME, "");
if (lastLogin is not empty) {
    mUsernameEditText.setText(lastLogin);
}
```